# Jquery to select all as default on document ready

Tags: c#, jquery

How would you select all items in drop down as default on document ready on page load ? It currently works so that when you select 'All' option, it selects all items in the list on change.

Current functionality as follows on codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/ExFJtHShnF

Thought about doing it like this but does not work as intended to because if all is selected, then you untick cheese and tick cheese, the drop down is no longer 'All' it states cheese as the text:

```
var checkboxes = $(':checkbox');
checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: u need to check in checkbox click event, if there is any other chebox checked or not

Comment: Sorry dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working answer: https://www.codeply.com/go/XxDu4DswTG

jQuery:

```
$('#basic').multiselect({
     //Add a default "select all" option instead of your custom one
     includeSelectAllOption: true,
     //Allow a number of displayed values in your menu
     numberDisplayed: 5
});

//Select all the values by default
$("#basic").multiselect('selectAll', false);
//Update the menu
$("#basic").multiselect('updateButtonText');
```

Then your HTML with the "all" option removed:

```
<div class="container">
    <select id="basic" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
    </select>
</div>
```